# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest_clicker'. What can I do? I try to use pytest in pycharm with 'Run pytest for ...'

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I want to use pytest in PyCharm for my unit tests. But if I try to run the tests inside PyCharm with as seen in the picture. I get the error shown below. I have found no workaround for it and no package pytest_clicker that I could install.

[image: Run 'pytest for test_Method]

I am working on Python 3.11 and pytest 7.4.2.

To fix it I searched in the internet after a workaround but I have not found one. I reinstalled pytest. Set pytest to the default test runner under Python Integrated Tools.

Sadly I had no further idea.

I simply would like to run testing methods within PyCharm without the need to rund the whole script.

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest_clicker']

Answer (score 0):

There's no package named `pytest_clicker`. Did you mean `pytest_click`? Run this in your python project terminal to install it: `pip install pytest_click`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. No I sadly really meant pytest_clicker. As you can see in the third last line of the picture: "pytest_clicker" is the output in the console.

The mentioned pytest_click is installed.

It is really confusing for me because I find nothing about pytest_clicker in the internet...